# Passing a parameter from button in the view to jQuery and use Ajax to pass that to a the controller method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am fairly new to Rails and Haml. I am trying to have a button in my view that holds a "key" parameter which will pass that same parameter and trigger a method in the controller using jQuery with Ajax.

Everything can be done behind the scenes in my other class (it's a POST REST request) and I don't need to view anything other than a success message. I have debugged all the variables and the routes, however, the Ajax is not catching the `key: parameter` for some reason. It keeps saying `undefined`. I tried to hardcode the `key` parameter in the controller method and everything else is confirmed working but just missing the parameter.

In my view I have this line:

```
%button#start{ key: @start_key }= start
```

In my process.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#start').on('click', function(){
        var start_key = $('button#start').attr('key');   <------------
         $.ajax({
            url: '/process/start_process',
            data: start_key
         })
         $('#started_msg').text('started !!!');
     });
});
```

In my controller.rb, I have this method:

```
def start_process
    Client.start_process(params[:key])
End
```

I wasn't sure if this is the correct way to do this. Please feel free to give me some comments or whether there is additional information needed.

Comment: What do you get when you run `$('button#start').attr('key');` in your javascript console?

Comment: it didn't say anything when i clicked it. no error but when i use a debugger start_key is undefined

Comment: I bet `@start_key` is nil, which means the attribute is never set. Confirm its value by outputting it to the html. Do you mean to use `@start_key` or `start`?

Comment: the @start_key is a parameter that selects which process from the Pervious page and I have double checked that variable it is getting the correct process key

Comment: Does `$('button#start')` return any elements?

Comment: I tried with just  var start_key = $('button#start'); the debugger said start_key undefined. But It is catching the button, since the started msg showed up after i clicked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few bits, see inline comments.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#start').on('click', function(){
        var start_key = $('button#start').attr('key');
         $.ajax({
            url: '/process/start_process',
            method: 'POST', // <-- POST instead of GET
            data: { // <-- POST an object instead of just the value
                key: start_key // <-- named param
            }
         })
         $('#started_msg').text('started !!!');
     });
});
```

Before when you were just sending back the key "bare", the params array would have looked like this:

```
{"my-key-value"=>nil}
```

Now that you post an object back to the rails app, the params hash should contain the key "key", and the right value, eg:

```
{key: "my-key-value"}
```

If you look at your rails server request logs you should be able to see the differences. It lists the request parameters (at least rails 4 does and I think rails 3 did too).

Comment: I got an no route error from my rails server. but rake routes saying there is a such route get /process/start_process. I was wondering if I have to change that to POST /process/start_process.  Also about the Object, I was wondering if you can explain what the comment named param means ?

Comment: I have changed the route to post and I got a ActionView::MissingTemplate error in my server. I was thinking if i need to add respond_to in my controller method

Comment: By named param I mean you're passing back a hash to the server, so your parameter has key/name. Before you were just passing back the parameter on its own, which means its 'unnamed', it becomes a key in the params array instead of a value. See the two hashes at the end of my post. Yes you need a respond_to/render/redirection. By default rails is looking for a `views/process/start_process.html/haml/erb/etc`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: understand the param means so i guess whenever I need to pass a param then i should use post.......good point... I guess I am looking for something like respond_to  respond_to do |format|
      format.js and do not render to view ? in my controller ?

Comment: i did respond_to {render nothing = true} .. now that server is happy but I am still not passing the parameter .

Comment: Great, what was the solution? Please post your own answer and accept it or edit this one and accept it.